# InvalidOperationException when invoking web service using threads VB. Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, web-services

I added a web reference to my project.

I'm using threads, they call to web service of this way:

```
Private Sub principal()
    Dim arrayH As New ArrayList
    Dim h As Thread
    Dim z As Integer = 150

    For i As Integer = 1 To Z
        h= New Thread(AddressOf doWork)
        arrayH.Add(h)
    Next


    For Each _h As Thread In arrayH
        _h.Start()
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub doWork()
    Dim service As webService.Query
    Dim parameter, response As String

    parameter = "..."'The parameter is a xml

    Try
        service = New Query
        response = service.Report(parameter)

    Catch ex As Exception
        'do something
    End Try

End Sub
```

When there are many threads (Z = 150) it throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException

There is an error in XML document (1, 279).

Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
```

In case that Z is small no problem. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

The error "Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed." is effectively a server-side problem. You could be asking for too many requests at once.